# How can I change the directory where cabal stores the documentation

Tags: haskell, configuration-files, cabal

I installed a custom Haskell toolchain with the prefix `$HOME/usr`, so the compiler lives in `$HOME/usr/bin/ghc` and the documentation in `$HOME/usr/share/doc/ghc/...`. The toolchain consists of a `ghc` installation, a `cabal` installation and all the libs you need. I set up `$PATH` in a way, that all these programs are in it. There is no other installation of these tools on my system.

Now I tried to install some other libraries. But I always got the same error when cabal tried to install the documentation:

```
~$ cabal install --global binary
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring binary-0.5.0.2...
Preprocessing library binary-0.5.0.2...
Building binary-0.5.0.2...
 ... snip ...
Registering binary-0.5.0.2...
cabal: /usr/local/share/doc: permission denied
```

How can I tell cabal where the documentation should live? I don't want to give this information again and again in the shell, so the best would be a config file. I want to have all the haskell related stuff in my home tree, to avoid destroying my system with a wrong command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you installing with "--global"?  By default this would put everything in /usr/local/.  If you do a standard per-user install the docs will be installed into your home directory and it should work fine.

That being said, this is configurable via a file.  The cabal config file is typically located at `~/.cabal/config/`.  Here's the relevant section of mine:

```
install-dirs global
  -- prefix: /usr/local
  -- bindir: $prefix/bin
  -- libdir: $prefix/lib
  -- libsubdir: $pkgid/$compiler
  -- libexecdir: $prefix/libexec
  -- datadir: $prefix/share
  -- datasubdir: $pkgid
  -- docdir: $datadir/doc/$pkgid
  -- htmldir: $docdir/html
  -- haddockdir: $htmldir
```

You can make whatever changes you like, just be sure to uncomment the lines.  There is also an "install-dirs user" section, which is used in per-user installs.

Comment: Is it enough to uncomment just the first line ?

Comment: Should I change `-- prefix:/usr/local` to `--prefix:~/mydir` or to `prefix:~/mydir` omitting 2 dashes (`--`) ? Also, can I then just cut `/usr/local/.cabal` folder to paste it in `~/mydir` ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the poster.  Why is there no clear documentation for how to do 
cabal install package --global
that prompts for sudo when permission is needed?
Doing
sudo cabal install package
is a bad idea because then you're building packages as root.  And you have to allow an internet connection to write to a file owned by root (you will have to populate /root/.cabal or something like that).

Here is a good reason why one would want to do this:
If I install ghc and the haskell platform through my linux package manager (there are good reasons for this ;), then if I do cabal install package
it will not recognize the packages that globally recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone actually posted a(n almost annoyingly) detailed description of how to do global installations (with either --global or install-dirs global) without running into permission errors.  The trick is to use root-cmd sudo in the cabal config file.
See,
http://jdgallag.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/cabal-install-to-global-using-sudo-but-do-not-build-as-root/